# Getting a certain format in a dictionary containing tuples and arrays in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

Im trying to create a data structure identical to the one displayed below, the structure is a printout of the variable. From what I can gather the stucture is a dictionary containing a tuple as a key, however the value is confusing me. The file that created this data structure doesn't contain the array library. What does the value corresponding to the tuple of zeroes concist of?

```
{(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0): 
    array([0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111,
           0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111])
}
```

Best regards

I was trying to replicate the data stucture.

Comment: just check the type of the values, you will find good insight there

Comment: It may be using some other library that uses `array` internally.

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely a Numpy array. You can read more about Numpy array here:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#what-is-an-array

Install Numpy:

```bash
pip install numpy
```

Then you can import `array` and define the variable:

```py
from numpy import array

data = {(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0): 
    array([0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111,
           0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111])
}
```

Or:

```py
import numpy as np

data = {(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0): 
    np.array([0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111,
           0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.11111111])
}
```